# "I will be available anytime during the morning, until 4pm"

Tags: future-tense, time

I am trying to answer someone regarding my availability for an interview with this sentence:

> I will be available anytime during the morning, until 4 pm.

Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: You could say: 'I'll be available anytime during the day until (or *up to*) 4pm'.

Answer (score 8):

It is grammatically correct, but illogical.

"Any time during the morning" means "between midnight and noon" but "until 4pm" means, well, "until 4pm."

So to say "In the morning until 4pm" doesn't really make sense.  Although most anyone will understand that you mean "In the morning or in the afternoon until 4pm."

I would simply say:

> I am available any time until 4pm.

There is no reason to specify morning at all in your case.